# JBullet NullPointer on step simulation in separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, bulletphysics, jbullet

I have a setup in my game where physics are updated in a separate thread with an implementation as follows

Physics Processor (Physics Thread)

```
public class PhysicsProcessor extends Runnable {
    private DynamicsWorld world;

    public PhysicsProcessor() {
        /* basic dynamics world setup with dvbt broadphase :P */
    }

    public synchronized getDynamicsWorld() { return world; }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* update time */

        //update phyics
        getDynamicsWorld().stepSimulation(/* delta time */);
    }
}
```

Example Object Creation In Main Thread

```
myPhysicsProcessor.getDynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(/* some rigid body created here */);
```

The problem is that when the game runs I occasionally get a null pointer exception in the separate thread on "stepSimulation", which was caused by setAabb in my dbvt broadphase.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to prevent this exception, or how to work around it?

Comment: When is `world` created?

Comment: it would be created by PhysicsProcessor's constructor which would be called somewhere in my main thread

Comment: That's probably the cause of the null. The code you presented here is fine. Can you post the constructor's code?

Comment: the code is a bit different as in world is dynamics world:broadphaseInterface = new DbvtBroadphase();
        collisionConfiguration = new DefaultCollisionConfiguration();
        collisionDispatcher = new CollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
        constraintSolver = new SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
        dynamicsWorld = new DiscreteDynamicsWorld(collisionDispatcher, broadphaseInterface, constraintSolver, collisionConfiguration);

Comment: i can tell you i know for a fact that the world is not null

Answer (score 0):

You could make the world `final` from the looks of it. Then that would show you the futility of synchronizing the access:

```
public class PhysicsProcessor extends Runnable {
    private final DynamicsWorld world;

    public synchronized DynamicsWorld getDynamicsWorld() { return world; } //why sync? it can't change
}
```

You see, when you do: `myPhysicsProcessor.getDynamicsWorld().addRigidBody(...)` the synchronization stops after the `getDynamicsWorld()` returns. So `addRigidBody(...)` is called outside of the safe synchronized context.

No, what you want to do is ensure that it is always used **within** a sync block:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    //update physics
    synchronized(this) {
      world.stepSimulation(/* delta time */);
    }
}

public void addBody(/*args here*/) {
    synchronized(this) {
      world.addRigidBody(/*args here*/);
    }
}
```

Now that's OK for one method, but if you find yourself wanting to do lots of methods of `DynamicsWorld` outside the runner in this way, or just want another choice, then this one requires no syncing:

```
public interface IWorldRunable {    
  void run(DynamicsWorld world);    
}    

public class PhysicsProcessor extends Runnable {
    private final DynamicsWorld world;
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<IWorldRunable> worldRunables = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<IWorldRunable>();

    public PhysicsProcessor() {
        /* basic dynamics world setup with dvbt broadphase :P */
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* update time */

        //run runables on world
        for(IWorldRunable runable : worldRunables)
          runable.run(world);

        //clear runables
        worldRunables.clear();

        //update phyics
        world.stepSimulation(/* delta time */);
    }

    public void do(IWorldRunable runnable) {
        worldRunables.add(runnable);
    }
}
```

Then you would do this, to add a body:

```
myPhysicsProcessor.do(new IWorldRunable(){      
  @Override
  public void run(DynamicsWorld world){
     world.addRigidBody(...);
  }
});
```

It will get executed before the next `stepSimulation` on the same thread as that, so no thread worries.